# Can an instance of a User Control be public?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, instance

I hope this doesn't seem like a weird question or something that should be avoided, but is it possible to make the instance of the control public so that it can be used in other classes?

For instance, in XAML the User Control is established by

`<local:MyControl x:Name="ControlName" />`

Which can be accessed on the same code-behind by simply calling `ControlName.UseMethod();` just like any instances of classes that I would make.

Now, while I could declare the instance of normal classes in the code-behind as public then use it freely, I don't have the option to do so here as it is being declared in the XAML which I can't make public directly.

I need to be able to access the contents of the User Control throughout other sections of the program and unable to use the methods I need as static.

My experience in programming is very little, learning from books and through small projects, which may explain any oddities in the question. Hope it's okay.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely **cannot** just make that control public. Controls in .NET are private member variables of their `Form`, `Page`, `Window`, etc. They are generated by the compiler into the appropriate "hidden" cs file, and are set to private at that point. You **can** expose them though, with a property that returns them:

```
public MyControl MyControlProperty { get { return myControlName; } }
```

Now, you should really *never* be doing this. Other classes shouldn't know the internals of your view classes, they should be invoking methods, changing data, etc to *cause* those internals to change.

Also, as this is WPF, you shouldn't even be doing *that*, instead you should use view models that can invoke methods on other view models (often through a model) to cause their associated views to react and update.

In short, yes, you can expose controls to the world, but if you have to do so, you are almost assuredly doing it totally wrong.

Comment: That said, if you can tell me what I can google to do it better, I'd be thankful. Just anything that can access controls that are on an instance of a user control so that I can update them during run-time. At least, that's as good as I can explain it.

Comment: @Gilgamesh You are correct that `UserControl` is a class like any other, but then again, so is `TextBox`. The basic concept here is that a form's controls are very *intentionally* private. There is no reason to directly expose them to other objects, as that makes the coupling *way* too tight. If you decide to do this, just use the property method I put in my answer (again, doing so means your design is in real trouble). As far as doing it better, look into the MVVM pattern. Here's a starting point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I'll avoid going through that route then as I don't want to pick up nasty practices. Also, I avoided trying to use MVVM stuff due to trying to reduce the learning curve with WPF but I see that doing so wasn't such a great idea. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Gilgamesh Come by the WPF room if you run into any confusion that isn't ready to be an SO question yet. I and others would be happy to help you learn some better practices :)